# Sitecore 7.2 and MVC 5, no view renderings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

From what I have read Sitecore 7.2 has native support for MVC (5) and I just installed a fresh version of Sitecore 7.2, on the very same machine I have ASP.net 4.5 and MVC 3,4 and 5 installed. the SQL Server is also running on the same machine (SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1) but once I try to create a new rendering within sitecore, there is no option to use "views/razor views". I only have the option to use `.ascx` or `xslt`.

Am I missing some sort of hidden configuration or something? Does it require Visual Studio to be installed as well on the same machine for MVC support?

Best regards,
Inx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to install Visual Studio on the machine and you don't have to change any configuration.

You can not add MVC renderings by default to the `Layout/Sublayouts` node (cause that's the place where ascx sublayouts go) but you should be able to add them to the `Layout/Renderings`. Below is the screenshot from the clean setup of Sitecore 7.2 rev 140526:

[image]

If you cannot add mvc renderings in that place on your instance, double check the version of Sitecore (e.g. check login screen) - maybe you're connected to the other instance of Sitecore running older version?